# KVO Observing AVPlayer causes App crash in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, ios13

I get w weird crash related to observing `AVPlayer.timeControlStatus` in iOS 13. It's not happening in iOS 12.

Here's the code for setting the observer up:

```
// stored in View Controller 
private var playerStateObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
@objc var player : AVPlayer?

// setting KVO after initialising AVPLayer
playerStateObservation = observe(\.player?.timeControlStatus) { [weak self] (object, change) in
    let playing = self?.player?.timeControlStatus == .playing
    self?.showPlayIcon(playing)
}
```

And here the function to stop observation. It's called in ViewController `deinit`.

```
func cleanUpObserver() {
    playerStateObservation?.invalidate()
    playerStateObservation = nil
}
```

The crash occurs in following situation:

1. Open ViewController with AVPlayer and start observation.
2. Go back to previous ViewController.
3. Dismiss the app to the background.
4. Bring back the app to the foreground.
5. Crash: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2b1bc593c)`

Here's the callstack of the crash.

[image]

Looks like the AVPlayer is trying to send notification to a observer that should already be invalidated and released from memory. Did anyone have a similar issue?

Comment: Seems like the only fix for this issue is using old KVO API.

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillDisappear` will be better place to remove observations dude.

Comment: In terms of this issue it makes no difference, I tested it.

Comment: could you try to use the old KVO api, we facing this issue too and decided fall back to old API.

Comment: I also didn't find any solution other than using old KVO api.